# How to upload image and user name in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to upload an image along with other details like (name, phone no, address).

Please suggest if any code available in nodejs and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

try this on client side- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

and this on Server - [express multer](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/nodejs-file-upload-using-multer-3a904516f6d2)

also if you're looking to save image in MongoDB take a look at this - [MongoDB GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: I have used this but I am not getting form value.